# AngularJS send HTML from controller to View with $sce not working

Tags: angularjs

I have the situation where I get raw html from a http call in my controller. I then want to send this raw html data to my view within angularjs. This however by default gets blocked by the AngularJs ngSantize module because the html data might be malicious.

I therefore included the ngSanitize module in the core of my app and use the $sce.trustAs  method to send my html to the view. This however only works partly. I do get the underline, bold and subscript tags that work, but the table tags are completely omitted. So I am wondering whether I did something wrong or whether this cannot be done.

I first include the ngSanitize module:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.core', [
            /* Angular modules */
            'ngAnimate',
            'ngSanitize',            

            /* Cross-app modules */
            'blocks.exception',
            'blocks.logger',
            'blocks.router',
            'blocks.filter',


            /* Cross-app service modules */
            'services.dateservice',
            'services.textservice',
            'services.sharepointservice',
            'services.applicationinsightsservice',
            'services.menuservice',

            /* 3rd-party modules */
            'AdalAngular',
            'ui.router',
            'restangular',
            'angular-loading-bar',
            'angular.filter',
            'ui.bootstrap',
            'ui.select',
            'ngStorage',
            'ct.ui.router.extras',
            'ct.ui.router.extras.core',
            'pascalprecht.translate',
           // 'ApplicationInsightsModule',
             'ui.grid'

          /* 'adf.widget.latestblogs',
            'adf.widget.peoplesearch'*/
        ]);
})();
```

In my settings config I have the following whitelists/blacklists:

```
angular.module('app').config(function ($sceDelegateProvider) {
        $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist(['**']);
    });

  $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|chrome-extension|skype|callto|sip|tel):/);
```

The html I send

```
<p>Dit is een test voor de foto van ggd</p>

<p> </p>

<div class="canvasRteResponsiveTable">
<div class="tableWrapper">
<table title="Table">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>a</td>
   <td>b</td>
   <td>c</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>x</td>
   <td>y</td>
   <td>z</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
,
,

<p> </p>

<p>xcccxcxc<s> cx</s> c<strong> xc</strong> c <u>dc </u>d v &copy; copyright</p>

<p> </p>

<p> </p>
```

In my controller I use the following code to set the data:

```
var cleanDataHtml = $sce.trustAs('html', cleanData);
console.log(cleanData);
vm.widget.rteContent = cleanDataHtml
```

And I bind it in the html view as follows:

```
   <article ng-if="widget.oneInternalName === 'richText'" class="widget-small-spacer">
                <p ng-bind-html="widget.rteContent"></p>
            </article>
```

My html renders  as below. Showing that bold and underline tags work but not the tables...

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Probably there's some CSS on page causing table tag to not seem like a table. Did you tried inspecting element and its CSS ?

Comment: Cannot believe that I didn't think of this. It indeed turns out the table is there and thus I totally looked at the wrong direction the whole time. Thanks you.